What does this symbol mean in this picture it's like a hex sign good or bad
What does this symbol mean??? One morning I was on my Chrome and all the sudden this popped up ain't ever happened to me before and then it disappeared but I got a screenshot before it did
What does this symbol mean in this picture it's like a hex sign good or bad

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The page loaded without most of its external resources, which can happen for any number of reasons (in this case perhaps it was slow internet — it's only really a problem if refreshing the page doesn't display it normally). The only external resources that loaded here were the SVG icons that should have been placed next to each line in "No credit check / No minimum balance / No activation fee", which were larger and stacked on top of each other because the CSS code positioning them properly was missing.
Here is a screenshot I took in Chrome Dev tools (Network tab) of the page without any external resources:

The icons are icon-checkmark-circle.svg, icon-coins.svg, and icon-lightning.svg.
